# Настройка proxy_pass на nginx

Tags: nginx, jenkins

Во внутренней сети есть jenkins, есть внешний nginx, нужно сделать proxy_pass. Проблема вся в том, что jenkins опубликован на http://yyy.yy.y.yyy:8080
а proxy_pass я делаю так

```
location /jenkins {
                proxy_pass http://yyy.yy.y.yyy:8080;
                proxy_redirect on;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                set_real_ip_from ххх.хх.х.х;
        }
```

и получается когда обратиться по внешнему адресу 
http://mydomain.ru/jenkins это дело перенаправится как http://yyy.yy.y.yyy:8080/jenkins, но такой страницы нет, и получаю 404

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

proxy_redirect off;

Добавить слеши в конец

location /jenkins/

proxy_pass http://yyy.yy.y.yyy:8080/;

Comment: Если вы нашли решение, добавьте его ответом, а не в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
location /jenkins/ {
    rewrite    /jenkins/(.*)    /$1  break;
    proxy_pass http://yyy.yy.y.yyy:8080;
    ...
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]